# How to find the `text` property of a Widget during testing in Flutter?

Tags: testing, text, dart, flutter

I have a piece of code that creates a Table of Text widgets, like this:

```
return Table(
  defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(120.0),
  children: <TableRow>[
    TableRow(
      children: <Widget>[Text('toffee'), Text('potato')],
    ),
    TableRow(
      children: <Widget>[Text('cheese'), Text('pie')],
    ),
  ],
);
```

I want to test that the first item in the Table is indeed the word 'toffee'. I set up my test and get to this part:

```
var firstCell = find
      .descendant(
        of: find.byType(Table),
        matching: find.byType(Text),
      )
      .evaluate()
      .toList()[0].widget;

  expect(firstCell, 'toffee');
```

This definitely doesn't work because `firstCell` is of type Widget, which is not equal to the String `toffee`.

I only see a `toString()` function, like this:

```
'Text("toffee", inherit: true, color: Color(0xff616161), size: 16.0,
 textAlign: left)'
```

How do I extract the `text` property to get the word `toffee`?

Right now it seems like all I can do is check that the `.toString().contains('toffee')` which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast your `firstCell` to `Text`.

```
var firstCell = find
    .descendant(
      of: find.byType(Table),
      matching: find.byType(Text),
    )
    .evaluate()
    .whereType<Text>()
    .first;
```

Then test `firstCell.data`

```
expect(firstCell.data, 'toffee');
```

Comment: Wow! That was it. Thanks you! Didn't realize we could cast it with `as` - is there a guide or documentation to that? My Dart Analyzer isn't a fan of it but I just added an `// ignore avoid_as`.

Comment: You can use a `whereType` clause. I edited my answer

Comment: Noted. Through that I found that there is also a `.where()` which is useful if you want to filter based on some other property, although this will still return an `Element`.

Comment: It seems like your solution with `.whereType<Text>` _should_ work, but now I am getting an empty Iterable of items. As comparison, without `.whereType`, I get:
`(Text("toffee", inherit: true, color: Color(0xff616161), size: 16.0, textAlign: left), Text("potato", inherit: true, color: Color(0xff616161), size: 16.0, textAlign: left), Text("cheese", inherit: true, color: Color(0xff616161), size: 16.0, textAlign: left), Text("pie", inherit: true, color: Color(0xff616161), size: 16.0, textAlign: left))`

Answer (score 8):

Rémi's example doesn't quite work - it may have worked at the time he answered, but at this time calling `whereType<Text>()` will always return an empty `Iterable` because `evaluate()` returns `Iterable<Element>`, not `Iterable<Widget>`. You can however get an `Element`'s Widget by calling `.widget` on it, so the following code should work:

```
Text firstText = find
    .descendant(
      of: find.byType(Table),
      matching: find.byType(Text),
    )
    .evaluate()
    .first
    .widget;

expect(firstText.data, 'toffee');
```

The OP was very close to having working code - there were only 2 minor issues:

- By using `var` instead of `Text`, the type of the variable was `Widget`
- The `Widget` was compared to a `String` - this could never return true - the intent was to compare a property of the `Widget` to the `String` - in the case of a `Text`, the `String` it displays is obtained by calling `.data` on the `Text`

**Edit:**

The `WidgetTester` now has utility functions for retrieving widgets: `widget(Finder)`, `widgetList(Finder)`, `firstWidget(Finder)` and `allWidgets`. So for the OP's use case you would be using `firstWidget` like so:

```
Text firstText = tester.firstWidget(
    find.descendant(
      of: find.byType(Table),
      matching: find.byType(Text),
    ));

expect(firstText.data, 'toffee');
```

Answer (score 2):

Find by text ?

```
expect(find.text('toffee'), findsOneWidget);
```

Comment: This only tells me that the text is somewhere on the screen, not that the Table's first cell's `text` property is the word 'toffee'

Answer (score 0):

You can use short form for any type of widgets:

```dart
expect(
     (find.byType(InAppWebView).evaluate().single.widget as InAppWebView)
          .initialUrl,
          'https://www.google.com/');
```